# Pycharm не видит aiogram_datepicker.views

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, datepicker

При импорте `aiogram_datepicker` вылезает ошибка

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram_datepicker.views'

Саму библиотеку обновила - не помогло.

Comment: как импортируете?

Comment: @ZxNuClear from aiogram_datepicker import Datepicker, DatepickerSettings
ref: https://pypi.org/project/aiogram-datepicker/